# Which browser versions are compatible with GWT Developer Plugin and macOS 10.14.5?

Tags: firefox, gwt, safari, macos-mojave, gwt-dev-mode

I'm currently trying to use GWT Developer Plugin in the envirnment macos-mojave.

Firefox tells me that I need versions from 3.0 - 26.0, so I tried versions of 23 and 24 but they crashed shortly after I run them.

Safari tells me that I need versions under 5.1, so I tried version 5.0.5 but it's not compatible with macos mojave. And then I tried OmniWeb 5.11 but it cannot even run in macos mojave.

Chrome tells me that "GWT Developer Plugin no longer works with Chrome".

So I'm wondering if it's possible to use GWT Developer Plugin in macos-mojave. It would be grateful if someone can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need the plugin.

Search for GWT SuperDevMode.
This works without plugin in is the standard way of using GWT for about 4 years.